# Javascript attach an object syntactic sugar?

Tags: javascript, syntactic-sugar

I have an object in my class like so:

```
this.options = {
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
     ...
};
```

I just wondered if there was a way to "attach" the options object to the current scope in Javascript, such that I can refer to `a` and `b` directly (instead of `this.options.a` and `this.options.b`). Something like:

```
attach(this.options);
var myVariable = a + 3; // 4
detach(this.options);
```

or

```
with( this.options, {
   // code here
 var myVariable = a + 3; // 4
});
```

In the above, the `attach` and `with` have the effect of taking all of the children of `this.options` and attaching them to the current scope so they are accessible via `a` instead of `this.options.a`. (The `with` version simply detaches `this.options` once you're done, enclosing the potentially-damaging attaching to within that scope).

As long as it works in the Spidermonkey/Mozilla engine, I don't mind if it's not portable.

I only mention this because of curiosity & laziness: all the nested names are getting annoying to type out, and I know that in the R language this is possible (in fact, the syntax in the snippets above is almost exactly what you'd write in R to achieve this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has a [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) that works similar to what you describe:

```
with (this.options) {
    var myVariable = a + 3;  // here a is actually this.options.a
}
```

However as you can see at the MDN article I linked to there are some cons to using it, because, e.g., of potential ambiguity. In the example above, `a` could be a property of `this.options`, or it could be a variable defined elsewhere, and looking just at that block there is no way to tell.

`with` is not recommended (and is forbidden in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode)).

There is a safe alternative though: create a variable that references (again in your example) `this.options`:

```
var o = this.options;

var myVariable = o.a + 3;
```

It's not quite as short as typing `a` on its own, but it's shorter than repeating `this.options` everywhere.

Comment: Aha, `with` is *exactly* what I was after. I understand the caveats that come with its use (the `with`/`attach` functions in R come with similar warnings/are treated with similar apprehension within the R community). cheers! (for the moment I was solving it with your second method).

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap you object in another object, with `attach` and `detach` methods as well as an internal cache to store the actual data object. then have the `attach` and `detach` methods provide `data` as `this` inside the callback:

```
function TheObject(data){
    var that = this;

    this.data = data;

    this.attach = function(callback){
        callback.apply(that.data);
    }

}

//wrap the object
var myobj = new TheObject({
    a: 1,
    b: 2
});


myobj.attach(function(){
    //"this" in here is the "data" in the object.
    //this.a
    //this.b
});
```